# Variables don't get updated

Tags: java, xml, spring, struts2, ldap

My goal is to get my application login/password to match with the LDAP.
Everything work, though it seems the variables don't get initialized.

It's a Java Application using Spring, Struts2 and Maven. The mapping looks Okay to me since it does :

**Console :**

```
2015-02-12 16:13:46,955 INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.loadProperties:178 - Loading properties file from URL [file:d:/Users/****/properties/match.properties]
2015-02-12 16:13:46,971 INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons:414 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10309a9: defining beans [project-properties,applicationGlobal]; root of factory hierarchy
2015-02-12 16:13:46,982 INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:209 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 341 ms
```

**web.xml :**

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**applicationContext.xml :**

```
<bean id="project-properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />        
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:/home/tomcat/properties/match-aaaa.properties</value>
                 <value>file:${user.home}/properties/match.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>      
    </bean> 

    <!-- ================================================ -->
    <bean id="applicationGlobal" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.Constants" scope="singleton" >
            <property name="aDURI" value="${ADURI}"/>
        <property name="aDBaseDN" value="${ADBaseDN}"/>
        <property name="aDRootUser" value="${ADRootUser}"/>
        <property name="aDRootPassword" value="${ADRootPassword}"/>
        <property name="aDGroupeAdmin" value="${ADGroupeAdmin}"/>
        <property name="aDGroupeSuperviseur" value="${ADGroupeSuperviseur}"/>
        <property name="aDGroupeUser" value="${ADGroupeUser}"/>         
        <property name="userProfile" value="${UserProfile}"/>
        <property name="token" value="${TOKEN}"/>       
    </bean>
```

And my **match.properties :** (values have been changed for obvious reason)

```
# ACTIVE DIRECTORY -- Authentification & Roles
ADURI=***
ADBaseDN=***
ADRootUser=***
ADRootPassword=***
ADGroupeAdmin=***
ADGroupeSuperviseur=***
ADGroupeUser=***
UserProfile=***
TOKEN=***
```

Well it seems that it does go to the location of the **match.properties** but it doesn't put the values in my variables...

I'm looking forward some help !

Here is the full **console :**

```
2015-02-12 16:46:11,736 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:57 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport@1edd647, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@d712ed], property=org]
2015-02-12 16:46:11,743 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.debug:57 - Checking ConfigurationProviders for reload.
2015-02-12 16:46:11,747 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - after Locale=fr_FR
2015-02-12 16:46:11,747 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - intercept } 
2015-02-12 16:46:12,010 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.debug:57 - Checking ConfigurationProviders for reload.
2015-02-12 16:46:18,456 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:57 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@d712ed], property=struts]
2015-02-12 16:46:18,457 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.debug:57 - Checking ConfigurationProviders for reload.
2015-02-12 16:46:18,457 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.debug:57 - Creating an DefaultActionProxy for namespace / and action name Login
2015-02-12 16:46:18,459 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - intercept '//Login' { 
2015-02-12 16:46:18,459 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - applied invocation context locale=fr_FR
2015-02-12 16:46:18,459 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - before Locale=fr_FR
2015-02-12 16:46:18,460 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:57 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction@1b1e91b, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@d712ed], property=struts]
2015-02-12 16:46:18,474 DEBUG org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.debug:57 - Bypassing //Login
2015-02-12 16:46:18,475 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.debug:57 - Setting static parameters {}
2015-02-12 16:46:18,475 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.debug:57 - Setting params NONE
2015-02-12 16:46:18,475 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.debug:57 - Setting params login => [ ***** ] pass => [ ***** ] 
2015-02-12 16:46:18,476 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - Property: login
2015-02-12 16:46:18,477 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - Class: com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction
2015-02-12 16:46:18,483 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - converter is null for property login. Mapping size: 0
2015-02-12 16:46:18,484 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - field-level type converter for property [login] = none found
2015-02-12 16:46:18,484 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - global-level type converter for property [login] = none found
2015-02-12 16:46:18,484 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@1b9295f]
2015-02-12 16:46:18,485 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - Property: pass
2015-02-12 16:46:18,486 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - Class: com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction
2015-02-12 16:46:18,486 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - field-level type converter for property [pass] = none found
2015-02-12 16:46:18,486 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - global-level type converter for property [pass] = none found
2015-02-12 16:46:18,487 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.debug:57 - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@1b9295f]
2015-02-12 16:46:18,487 DEBUG org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.debug:57 - Validating //Login with method execute.
2015-02-12 16:46:18,497 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.debug:57 - Invoking validate() on action com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction@1b1e91b
2015-02-12 16:46:18,498 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrefixMethodInvocationUtil.debug:57 - cannot find method [validateExecute] in action [com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction@1b1e91b]
2015-02-12 16:46:18,499 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrefixMethodInvocationUtil.debug:57 - cannot find method [validateDoExecute] in action [com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction@1b1e91b]
2015-02-12 16:46:18,499 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.debug:57 - Executing action method = null
2015-02-12 16:46:18,515 INFO  com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction.execute:108 - ERREUR: java.lang.NullPointerException
2015-02-12 16:46:18,516 INFO  com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction.execute:124 - ERREUR: L'utilisateur **** n'est pas user
2015-02-12 16:46:18,516 WARN  com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction.execute:141 - AD Authentification FAILED!!!
2015-02-12 16:46:18,517 DEBUG org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult.debug:57 - Redirecting to finalLocation /HelloWorldStruts2/context/errorLog.jsp
2015-02-12 16:46:18,518 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - after Locale=fr_FR
2015-02-12 16:46:18,518 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.debug:57 - intercept } 
2015-02-12 16:46:18,523 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.debug:57 - Checking ConfigurationProviders for reload.
2015-02-12 16:46:18,524 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.debug:57 - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@d712ed], property=org]
```

---

As requested **LoginAction.java :**

```
public class LoginAction extends BaseAction  {

    /**
     * Serial Version UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    


    private String login;
    private String pass;

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LoginAction.class);




    public String execute(){
        boolean auth = false;
        UserProfile userProfile=new UserProfile();
        String token = getLogin() + "#" + getPass();

        //bouchon
        /*
        if("admin".equals(getLogin())){
            userProfile.setLogin(getLogin());
            userProfile.setAdmin(true);
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(getApplicationGlobal().getUserProfile(), userProfile);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        if("superviseur".equals(getLogin())){
            userProfile.setSuperviseur(true);
            userProfile.setLogin(getLogin());
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(getApplicationGlobal().getUserProfile(), userProfile);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        if("user".equals(getLogin())){
            userProfile.setUser(true);
            userProfile.setLogin(getLogin());
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(getApplicationGlobal().getUserProfile(), userProfile);
            return SUCCESS;
        } 
        */


        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + getLogin() + "))";
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String domain = getApplicationGlobal().getaDURI();
        domain = domain.substring(domain.indexOf(".") + 1);

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, getApplicationGlobal().getaDURI());
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, getLogin() + "@" + domain);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);


        try {
            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            NamingEnumeration sr = ctx.search(getApplicationGlobal().getaDBaseDN(), searchFilter, searchCtls);

            while (sr.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult r = (SearchResult) sr.next();
                logger.debug("LDAP Info:" + r.getNameInNamespace());
                Attribute members = r.getAttributes().get("memberOf");
                logger.debug("LDAP Number of Group for this user:" + members.size());
                NamingEnumeration<String> emembers = (NamingEnumeration<String>) members.getAll();
                while (emembers.hasMore()) {
                    String ldapGroup = emembers.next();
                    String myLdapGroup = getFirstLdapValue(ldapGroup, null);
                    logger.debug("LDAP Group:" + myLdapGroup);
                    if(myLdapGroup!=null){
                        myLdapGroup=myLdapGroup.toLowerCase();
                        if (myLdapGroup.equals(getApplicationGlobal().getaDGroupeAdmin().toLowerCase())) {
                            userProfile.setAdmin(true);
                        }
                        else if(myLdapGroup.equals(getApplicationGlobal().getaDGroupeSuperviseur().toLowerCase())) {
                            userProfile.setSuperviseur(true);

                        }
                        else if(myLdapGroup.equals(getApplicationGlobal().getaDGroupeUser().toLowerCase())) {
                            userProfile.setUser(true);

                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //throw new FunctionalException(FunctionalException.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, e, ERROR);
----->line108               logger.info("ERREUR: "+e);
        }

        //on ne retient que les roles "utiles"
        if(userProfile.getIsAdmin()){
            logger.info("L'utilisateur "+login+" est admin");
            userProfile.setSuperviseur(false);
            userProfile.setUser(false);
            auth = true;
        }
        else{
            if(userProfile.getIsSuperviseur()){
                logger.info("L'utilisateur "+login+" est superviseur");
                userProfile.setUser(false);
                auth = true;
            }
            else{
                if(!userProfile.isUser()){
                    logger.info("ERREUR: L'utilisateur "+login+" n'est pas user");
                }
                else{
                    auth = true;
                    logger.info("L'utilisateur "+login+" est user");
                }
            }
        }
        if (auth){
            userProfile.setLogin(getLogin());
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(getApplicationGlobal().getUserProfile(), userProfile);
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(getApplicationGlobal().getToken(), token);
            logger.warn("AD Authentification SUCCESS!");
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        else {
            logger.warn("AD Authentification FAILED!!!");
            return "notLogged";
        }

    }

    /**
     * Retourne la premiere valeur d'un chaine de type ldap (csv)
     * 
     * Exemple : CN=GG_Appli_Comptage_Production,OU=Atelier_Comptage,OU=Appli,OU=Groups,OU=Nanterre,OU=Altares,OU=Corp,DC=altares,DC=loc retourne
     * GG_Appli_Comptage_Production
     * 
     */
    private String getFirstLdapValue(final String ldapCsvValues, final Integer position) {
        String myLdapCsvValues = ldapCsvValues;
        Integer myPosition = position;
        if (position == null) {
            myPosition = 0;
        }
        if (myLdapCsvValues == null) {
            return null;
        }
        myLdapCsvValues = myLdapCsvValues.replace("\\,", "");
        String values[] = myLdapCsvValues.split(",");
        String value0[] = values[myPosition].split("=");
        return value0[1];
    }

    /*public Map authenticate(String user, String pass) {
        String returnedAtts[] = { "sn", "givenName", "mail" };
        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";

        logger.info("authenticate(" + user + ", xxx)");

        // Create the search controls
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

        // Specify the search scope
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

        LdapContext ctxGC = null;

        try {
            ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            // Search objects in GC using filters
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                Map amap = null;
                if (attrs != null) {
                    amap = new HashMap();
                    NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();
                    while (ne.hasMore()) {
                        Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
                        amap.put(attr.getID(), attr.get());
                    }
                    ne.close();
                }
                return amap;
            }
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            logger.warn("ERREUR LDAP:" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }*/

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the spring version you are using?

Comment: spring 2.5.6 for all jars

Comment: Please show your action, and tell us what's on line 108

Comment: action is in my first post and i put in bold line 108

Comment: ${user.home} resolving to correct location? Is the properties in match-aaaa.properties generated?

Comment: Well that's the part i'm not sure. It seems that it loads the file and apply them to the beans but it looks like that it's all it does because my variables still get a _null_ value...

Comment: In that line only the logger can be null... :|

Comment: So what is exactly not working? If you are not sure that your properties are loaded then don't ignore resource not found.